# Simple means to save web input to a Sharepoint list

Tags: list, sharepoint

In Sharepoint 2007, I wish to create a simple form on a public facing web page to insert a new list item - username.

I'm don't need anything fancy, so I'm hoping for a fairly simple solution.

I see this being accomplished in 2 parts:
1. capturing the user's Sharepoint ID, then
2. Inserting the user's ID into the list.

I thought the Form Web Part, pointing to my list, would be the way to go, but it appears the Form Web Part can't be used to insert new list items; but maybe I'm wrong.

I'm looking for any comment, suggestions, tips, examples, etc. for doing parts 1 and/or 2.

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Lists have new item forms by default. The filename of the form is NewForm.aspx.
Look for your new item form at http://[your site]/lists/[your list]/NewForm.aspx

If you'd like to add the new form to a different page than above, use SharePoint Designer 2007 and to [insert a custom list form](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3f-a3HDXeqM).

Also, the user's id is stored in the Created By and Modified By fields of the list.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'll look into your "new item forms" suggestion; but your 2nd suggestion raises an interesting thought: I'm trying to capture the user's ID to put in the list, but a user's action to add ANYTHING to the list will automatically store the user's ID in the Created By field, so I just need a user to add something to the list, sounds correct? My ultimate goal is to record all user IDs of users who check a checkbox. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: After looking at your "new item forms" suggestion, this form would need to be incorporated with the other public facing pages sharing the same layout and master layout. Can this "new item form" be easily transformed into such a page? Thanks.

Comment: One last point, the Created By column appears to show first and last name, which may not be unique amongst users. I was hoping for a unique way of identfying users. Any coments? Thanks again, have a good weekend.

Comment: Let me know if the edit answer's the question from your comment. Also, created by does contain the user's login information, not just their first and last name.